# TextView with editable parts

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to have a `TextView`, where certain "empty spaces" can be edited, but the rest is constant. I'm aware of that this is easy for prefixes and suffixes, but in my case most of the text is fixed, and the editable parts can be anywhere.

I plan to parse text like this (just longer):

```
Blah blah blah ______ text text
text _____ text text blah blah
```

This should create a view like a `TextView`, but the parts where there are underscores should be editable.

Is there some kind of View in the SDK that could help me with this? If not, how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: For editable parts take **Edit text** and  give hint as ____(underscore) and for non editable part use  TextView

Comment: So I just cut my text into pieces of constant and editable parts, and then place TextViews and EditTexts in some kind of layout. Could work, thanks, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` is a `TextView`. Use a `TextView`:

```
textView.setCursorVisible(true);
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
textView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
textView.requestFocus(); //triggers soft keyboard to show up
```

Then add [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher):

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start are about to be replaced by new text with length after.
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // 
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // 
    }
});
```

Then you can set the characters to be fixed or blank.